# How can I use CMake and CPack with a dependency that overwrites my variables?

Tags: cmake, dependencies, cpack, cmocka

I'm trying to use CPack to package my project, but I've run into an issue with one of my dependencies.

First, I am trying to use modern CMake style by relying on targets and dependencies modeled between targets using `target_link_libraries`. My project uses the [CMocka](https://cmocka.org) library as a dependency. I have added the CMocka repo as a git submodule and I have `add_subdirectory(cmocka_dir)` in my own `CMakeLists.txt` file.

I also use CPack with the `TGZ` generator to gather all my files into an archive. I simply `set(CPACK_GENERATOR TGZ)` and `include(CPack)` in my `CMakeLists.txt`. I have found that this takes care of everything, that is, until I started using CMocka. CMocka sets a lot of `CPACK_xxx` [variables](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.16/module/CPack.html#variables-common-to-all-cpack-generators) inside *its* root `CMakeLists.txt`. I believe that when I include CMocka's subdirectory in my own project, these variables propagate inside my CMake scope and mess with my packaging process.

My question is how I can fix this. Specifically:

1. Is there a way to isolate CMocka in its own environment, or otherwise prevent it from breaking my packaging process?
2. Am I doing it wrong by including CMocka using `add_subdirectory`?
3. Am I doing CPack wrong by just setting `CPACK_GENERATOR` and doing `include(CPack)`?

Thanks for your thoughts.

Comment: Do not include the external library in your own project. Instead, download, build and install the external library in your system, and use in your project `find_package(cmocka)` following some documentation like [this one](https://re-ws.pl/2018/10/using-cmocka-for-unit-testing-c-code/).

Comment: and as an addendum to @Pedro comment: build native packages (DEB/RPM/NugGet/...) of all your third-parties and store in the (private) repo. It'll make your development environment reproduceable and easy to deploy by anyone familiar w/ `apt`,`yum`,`nuget`...

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. Since we're cross-compiling for multiple platforms I'm trying to avoid unnecessarily installing dependencies to my system (or sysroot). As far as I understand this is also a CMake best practice?